# Need help debugging greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, greasemonkey

I'm quite new here, and just as new with GM scripting. With the help of some of the members here, Brock and others, I'm making progress.

I currently have the problem of debugging Greasemonkey scripts, but for some reason I'm not getting the hang of it. My first problem, to debug using console.log for firebug.

Sometimes I find the logs, most of the times I cant find anything there, guess I'm using it wrongly. Then trying to use alert in order to see variable values... same story.

I'm currently trying to get a script going to handle some auctions on the site [Trada.net](http://www.trada.net/p_home.aspx) with the great help of Brock Adams, we got more than halfway there, but I'm still hitting my head on JS scripting... quiet a new experience, if u take I was used to turbo pascal 15 + years ago.:)

Well, currently this is what I got together on the script:

```
 // ==UserScript==
// @name           bid up to test3
// @include         http://www.trada.net/*
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==


//--- Create a cell for transmitting the date from page scope to GM scope.
$('body'). prepend ('<div id="LatestJSON_Data"></div>');

var J_DataCell          = $('#LatestJSON_Data');


//--- Eavesdrop on the page's AJAX calls and paste the data into our special div.
unsafeWindow.$('body').ajaxSuccess (
    function (event, requestData)
    {
        J_DataCell.text (requestData.responseText);
    }
);

// **bid function and var's
// **var interval            = 50;
// **var bidClickTimer       = setInterval (function() {BidClick (); }, interval);
// **var numBidClicks        = 0;
// **var A1reset_go          = false;



// **function BidClick1 ()
// **{var //bidBtn1=document.getElementById("ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_AirtimeAuctionItem1_btn_BidButton");


//**    numBidClicks++;
//**    if (numBidClicks > 10)
//**    {   Alert("check10");
//**        clearInterval (bidClickTimer);
//**        bidClickTimer   = "";
//**    }
//**    else
//**    {   Alert("check11");
//**        bidBtn1.click (1);

//**    }
//**};

//**end bid function

//--- Listen for changes to the special div and parse the data.
J_DataCell.bind ('DOMSubtreeModified', ParseJSON_Data);

function ParseJSON_Data ()
{

//**my var
//**var auction_type ;A1_upto;A1_start;A1_current;A1_reset;
//**end my var

    //--- Get the latest data from the special cell and parse it.
    var myJson              = J_DataCell.text ();
    var jsonObj             = $.parseJSON (myJson);

    //--- The JSON should return a 2-D array, named "d".
    var BidDataArray        = jsonObj.d;

    //--- Loop over each row in the array.
    $.each (
        BidDataArray,
        function (rowIndex, rowValue) {

            //--- Print the 7th column.
            console.log ('Row: ' + (parseInt (rowIndex) + 1) + ' Column: 7  Value: ' + rowValue[6]);

//** my part
//**   Alert("check1");
//**  auction_type=parseInt (rowValue[4]);
//**   if (auction_type== 1)
//**
//**     {Alert("check2");
//**      A1_upto=parseInt (rowValue[12]);
//**       Alert("check3");
//**      A1_current=parseInt (rowValue[8]);
//**       Alert("check4");
//**      A1_reset=rowValue[16];
//**       if (A1_reset != "null")
//**         {Alert("check5");
//**          A1reset_go='true';
//**          };
//**       if (A1_reset == "null") and (A1reset_go=='true')
//**         {Alert("check6");
//**          A1reset_go=false;
//**          Alert("check7"); 
//**          A1_start=rowValue[8];
//**          };
//**        if  ((A1_current - A1_start) <= (A1_upto - 10))
//**          {Alert("check8");
//**           BidClick1 ();
//**           };
//**      };

//** end my part

      };
    );
}


//--- Format our special cell with CSS.  Add "visibility: hidden;" or "display: none;", if desired.
GM_addStyle ( (<><![CDATA[
    #LatestJSON_Data
    {
        background:         gold;
        border:             3px ridge #0000DD;
        font-size:          10px;
        margin:             0 2em;
        padding:            1ex 1em;
        width:              94%;
        opacity:            0.8;
        overflow:           hidden;
        z-index:            666;
        position:           absolute;
        color:              black;
    }
]]></>).toString () );
```

Basically, so far, it did create  a cell in which it displays all the auction data which was put into an array `BidDataArray`.

I want to use the data in the array, which is updated every second, to get certain pieces of data,and then decide whether or not to click on the bid button.

For the first auction I got to a stand still. The timer auctions I got it to work to click every few seconds.

On the first auction I basically want to:

1. Check which auction it is,
2. Find out if it is the first bid for auction,
3. Get the bid up to amount,
4. Do calculations to start clicking the last 10 clicks of the auction.
5. Reset the starting amount.

Sounds quite simple, but without a debugger and very little knowledge about Js and GM, it is keeping me quite busy. I've tried putting my Var's in console log, but cant track them. might have declared them wrongly, or used them wrongly... but I cant see the mistake, and I don't have an debugger to test them.

Will a java debugger work? but it is not linked to the site...

Also, the moment I added my parts into Brock's code, it didn't display the cell with the info any more... so somewhere I broke his code I cant find the problem... Before i added anything to his code, it worked well, then i added my parts, it didnt work any more, so i took it out by using "//". so the script should skip it, but his parts dont work anymore. I tried adding "alerts", but cant seem to find the problem. all my parts is marked with "//**" and should be inactive at the moment.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I've put the latst changes that I've tried to this script, but still ni luck. Is there any way to compiler errors on this Gm script? to see where i'mgoing wrong?... the main aim is to get it running with all the parts  marked as //**, that is the actual parts that started the unresponsiveness of the script.

Comment: Did this get resolved... By later questions, perhaps?

Comment: Yes thanks. Currently only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297356

Answer (score 1):

Well, I didnt get much response from here, but I've tried...:( I managed to get it debugged 90%, but here is my answer sofar...will update it after i've found a way aroud the minor glitches..:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            let's try 3.42
// @include         http://www.trada.net/*
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
var auctiontyp = 0;var aupto = 0;var A1_start  = 0;var A1_current = 0;var A1_rest= 'x';
// **bid function and var's
var interval            = 50;
var bidClickTimer       = setInterval (function() {BidClick1 (); }, interval);
var numBidClicks        = 0;
var A1reset_go          = false;

function BidClick1 ()

{var bidBtn1=document.getElementById("ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_AirtimeAuctionItem1_btn_BidButton");


    numBidClicks++;
    if (numBidClicks > 3)
    {   alert("check10");
       clearInterval (bidClickTimer);
        bidClickTimer   = "";
    }
    else
    {   alert('check11');
        //bidBtn1.click (1);

    }
};



// end bid function

var myJson              = '{"d":[["","","y","ZAR","1","49517","6458, 8270, 8270, 8270, 7635",null,"1.40","6458","0:13:30","","12","","C","30",null],["y","-00:00","y","ZAR","2","49593","6458, 6458, 6458, 6458, 6458",null,"2.92","6458","0:13:37","","12","","L","12","Ve4mYdrvkkQMKxBH1\/1VMtDTCDQBRspg5jB8jjY08zg="],["","","y","ZAR","3","49058","7456, 9216, 6458, 5153, 7456",null,"194.40","7456","0:00:31","","1100","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","4","49597","2935, 6554",null,"1.22","2935","0:01:16","","12","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","5","49590","4440, 0518, 5343, 2625, 4848",null,"0.95","4440","0:15:58","","5","","L",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","6","49591","4848, 4440, 4440, 0518, 2625",null,"1.81","4848","0:16:05","","12","","L",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","7","49595","6458",null,"5.55","6458","0:04:13","","55","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","8","49596","",null,"2.90","NONE","0:04:35","","29","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","9","49496","6458, 2427, 2427, 7863, 5845",null,"2.56","6458","0:06:07","","10","","B",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","10","49524","6458, 2427, 7863, 7863, 5845",null,"1.67","6458","0:06:00","","5","","B",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","11","49539","6458, 2427, 7863, 7863, 0764",null,"2.02","6458","0:04:25","","10","","B",null,null]]}'
var jsonObj             = $.parseJSON (myJson);

//--- The JSON should return a 2-D array, named "d".
var arrayOfAuctions     = jsonObj.d;

//--- Loop over each row in the array.
$.each (
    arrayOfAuctions,
    function (rowIndex, singleAuctionData) {

        //--- Print the 7th column.
        console.log ('Row: ' + (parseInt (rowIndex) + 1) + ' Column: 7  Value: ' + singleAuctionData[6]);
alert('test3.41');
auctiontyp=parseInt (singleAuctionData[4]);
   if (auctiontyp== 1)

     {
   aupto=parseInt (singleAuctionData[15]);alert('check2.6');
       alert('check3 '+(singleAuctionData[8]));
      A1_current=parseFloat (singleAuctionData[8]);
      alert('check4 '+(singleAuctionData[16]));
      A1_rest=singleAuctionData[16];
       alert(A1_rest);
       if (A1_rest != 'null')
         {alert('check5');
          A1reset_go=true;
          };
       alert('check5.1');
       alert(A1reset_go);
       if (A1_rest == 'null') and (A1reset_go==true)
         {alert('check6');
          A1reset_go=false;
          alert('check7'); 
          A1_start=singleAuctionData[8];
         };
          alert('check7.3');
         alert((A1_current) );
         alert(( A1_start));
         alert((aupto) );
        if  (((A1_current - A1_start)*100) < (aupto - 10))
          {alert('check8');
           //BidClick1 ();
           };

     };
    }
);
```

My current problems on this script:

1.The "BidClick1" function runs in the beginning of the script without being called, i only call it close to the end, but then it is not running..
2.This part:

```
A1_rest=singleAuctionData[16];
           alert(A1_rest);
           if (A1_rest != 'null')
             {alert('check5');
              A1reset_go=true;
              };
           alert('check5.1');
           alert(A1reset_go);
           if (A1_rest == 'null') and (A1reset_go==true)
             {alert('check6');
              A1reset_go=false;
              alert('check7'); 
              A1_start=singleAuctionData[8];
             };
```

is not executing correctly., for this array,"arrayOfAuctions", on the first segmant, that im doing all the tests on, "A1_rest" should be = to "null", but it's not, thus it executes:"

```
if (A1_rest != 'null')
                 {alert('check5');
                  A1reset_go=true;
                  };"
```

and also, it doesnt execute this statement :
"

```
 if (A1_rest == 'null') and (A1reset_go==true)
                 {alert('check6');
                  A1reset_go=false;
```

correctly, it should only execute if A1_rest="null" AND A1_reset_go is true. It executes no matter which one is true,and if i put it as:`if ((A1_rest == 'null') and (A1reset_go==true))` ,it doesnt run the script at all.

If any1 got an complete answer, i will mark it as such.
Thanks.
                  alert('check7'); 
                  A1_start=singleAuctionData[8];
                 };" executes always