# Getting requests from a website and retrieving the response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I am trying to monitor a website ([www.bidcactus.com](http://www.bidcactus.com)). While on the website I open up Firebug, go to the net tab, and click the XHR tab.

I want to take the responses of the requests and save it to a mySql database (I have a local one running on my computer(XAMPP).

I have been told to do a variety of things mainly using jQuery or JavaScript but I'm not experienced either so I was wondering if anyone can help me out here.

Someone suggested me this link 
[Using Greasemonkey and jQuery to intercept JSON/AJAX data from a page, and process it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092754/using-greasemonkey-and-jquery-to-intercept-json-ajax-data-from-a-page-and-proces/6093522#6093522)

Its using Greasemonkey as well which I don't know much about either...

Thanks in advance for any help

Example/more detail:
While monitoring the requests sent(via firebug) I see below

```
http://www.bidcactus.com/CactusWeb/ItemUpdates?rnd=1310684278585
The response of this link is the following:
{"s":"uk5c","a":[{"w":"MATADORA","t":944,"p":5,"a":413173,"x":10},   
{"w":"1000BidsAintEnough","t":6,"p":863,"a":413198,"x":0}, 
{"w":"YourBidzWillBeWastedHere","t":4725,"p":21,"a":413200,"x":8}, 
{"w":"iwillpay2much","t":344,"p":9,"a":413201,"x":9}, 
{"w":"apcyclops84","t":884,"p":3,"a":413213,"x":14}, 
{"w":"goin_postal","t":165,"p":5,"a":413215,"x":12}, 
{"w":"487951","t":825,"p":10,"a":413218,"x":6}, 
{"w":"mishmash","t":3225,"p":3,"a":413222,"x":7}, 
{"w":"CrazyKatLady2","t":6464,"p":1,"a":413224,"x":2}, 
{"w":"BOSS1","t":224,"p":102,"a":413230,"x":4}, 
{"w":"serbian48","t":62,"p":2,"a":413232,"x":11}, 
{"w":"Tuffenough","t":1785,"p":1,"a":413234,"x":1}, 
{"w":"apcyclops84","t":1970,"p":1,"a":413240,"x":13}, 
{"w":"Tuffenough","t":3524,"p":1,"a":413244,"x":5}, 
{"w":"Cdm17517","t":1424,"p":1,"a":413252,"x":3}],"tau":"0"}
```

I understand what this information and I think I could format it myself however the website randomly creates new requests.
Example `http://www.bidcactus.com/CactusWeb/ItemUpdates?rnd=XXXXXXXXXXXX`
and I'm not sure how it creates them.

So I'm needing to get the response for all the requests that are for item updates and send the information to a mysql database.

Comment: This is possible with Greasemonkey, but it's not much simpler than the link you referenced.  [More detail would help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).   For example, save the source, of the page you want to monitor, to pastebin.com and then indicate which parts you want to monitor and post.   Consider breaking the problem/question into bite-sized chunks.  PS: The target site does not appear to use jQuery, but it does use the [YUI Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/).

Comment: Edited the first post with as much more information as I could

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  The task is not too difficult, but it could get involved; so it may take me a day or two to post an answer, if nobody beats me to it.  Meanwhile, people have posted a fair amount about [intercepting Ajax calls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/629671/331508).  Try some code and see how it goes. ;)

Comment: Will do, Ill start playing around with greasemonkey and see what I can do. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Having some difficulty as ive never really used greasemonkey before, played around with some code from the link you provided but couldnt get it do to anything? Looked at some tutorials and made sure I included everything but still nothing happened...

Comment: Anybody still looking into this? Brock if you need payment for a solution Id gladly pay 20-50$? Or is it harder/worth more than that?

Comment: Ok.  I see I sort of promised to work on it, so I'll put it back near the top of my SO-time list. Should have something in a day or so.  But normally, [people expect to see more effort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  That may be why no one else tackled it. ;)   (Plus, the task in general may not be difficult, but specific web sites might be a bear (some web masters try like heck to prevent such exploits) ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, here's working code, somewhat tuned for that site (front page, no account, only).

**Instructions for use:**

1. Install the GM script.  Note that it is Firefox only, for now.
2. Observe it running in Firebug's console, and tune the filter section (clearly marked), to target the data you are interested in. (Maybe the whole `a` array?)

   Note that it can take several seconds after "Script Start" is printed, for the ajax intercepts to start.
3. Setup your web application and server to receive the data.  The script posts JSON, so PHP, for example, would grab the data, like so:

   ```
    $jsonData   = json_decode ($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
   ```
4. Point the script to your server.
5. Voilà. She is done.

---

```
/******************************************************************************
*******************************************************************************
**  This script intercepts ajaxed data from the target web pages.
**  There are 4 main phases:
**      1)  Intercept XMLHttpRequest's made by the target page.
**      2)  Filter the data to the items of interest.
**      3)  Transfer the data from the page-scope to the GM scope.
**          NOTE:   This makes it technically possibly for the target page's
**                  webmaster to hack into GM's slightly elevated scope and
**                  exploit any XSS or zero-day vulnerabilities, etc.  The risk
**                  is probably zero as long as you don't start any feuds.
**      4)  Use GM_xmlhttpRequest () to send the data to our server.
*******************************************************************************
*******************************************************************************
*/
// ==UserScript==
// @name            _Record ajax, JSON data.
// @namespace       stackoverflow.com/users/331508/
// @description     Intercepts Ajax data, filters it and then sends it to our server.
// @include         http://www.bidcactus.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

DEBUG   = true;
if (DEBUG)  console.log ('***** Script Start *****');


/******************************************************************************
*******************************************************************************
**  PHASE 1 starts here, this is the XMLHttpRequest intercept code.
**  Note that it will not work in GM's scope.  We must inject the code to the
**  page scope.
*******************************************************************************
*******************************************************************************
*/
funkyFunc   = ( (<><![CDATA[

    DEBUG           = false;
    //--- This is where we will put the data we scarf. It will be a FIFO stack.
    payloadArray    = [];   //--- PHASE 3a

    (function (open) {
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, async, user, pass)
        {
            this.addEventListener ("readystatechange", function (evt)
            {
                if (this.readyState == 4  &&  this.status == 200)  //-- Done, & status "OK".
                {
                    var jsonObj = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObj = JSON.parse (this.responseText);   // FF code.  Chrome??
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        //if (DEBUG)  console.log (err);
                    }
                    //if (DEBUG)  console.log (this.readyState, this.status, this.responseText);

                    /******************************************************************************
                    *******************************************************************************
                    **  PHASE 2:    Filter as much as possible, at this stage.
                    **              For this site, jsonObj should be an object like so:
                    **                  { s="1bjqo", a=[15], tau="0"}
                    **              Where a is an array of objects, like:
                    **                  a   417387
                    **                  p   1
                    **                  t   826
                    **                  w   "bart69"
                    **                  x   7
                    *******************************************************************************
                    *******************************************************************************
                    */
                    //if (DEBUG)  console.log (jsonObj);
                    if (jsonObj  &&  jsonObj.a  &&  jsonObj.a.length > 1) {
                        /*--- For demonstration purposes, we will only get the 2nd row in
                            the `a` array. (Probably stands for "auction".)
                        */
                        payloadArray.push (jsonObj.a[1]);
                        if (DEBUG)  console.log (jsonObj.a[1]);
                    }
                    //--- Done at this stage!  Rest is up to the GM scope.
                }
            }, false);

            open.call (this, method, url, async, user, pass);
        };
    } ) (XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
]]></>).toString () );


function addJS_Node (text, s_URL)
{
    var scriptNode                      = document.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                     = "text/javascript";
    if (text)  scriptNode.textContent   = text;
    if (s_URL) scriptNode.src           = s_URL;

    var targ    = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || d.body || d.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}

addJS_Node (funkyFunc);


/******************************************************************************
*******************************************************************************
**  PHASE 3b:
**  Set up a timer to check for data from our ajax intercept.
**  Probably best to make it slightly faster than the target's
**  ajax frequency (about 1 second?).
*******************************************************************************
*******************************************************************************
*/
timerHandle = setInterval (function() { SendAnyResultsToServer (); }, 888);

function SendAnyResultsToServer ()
{
    if (unsafeWindow.payloadArray) {
        var payload     = unsafeWindow.payloadArray;
        while (payload.length) {
            var dataRow = JSON.stringify (payload[0]);
            payload.shift ();   //--- pop measurement off the bottom of the stack.
            if (DEBUG)  console.log ('GM script, pre Ajax: ', dataRow);

            /******************************************************************************
            *******************************************************************************
            **  PHASE 4: Send the data, one row at a time, to the our server.
            **  The server would grab the data with:
            **      $jsonData   = json_decode ($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
            *******************************************************************************
            *******************************************************************************
            */
            GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
                method:     "POST",
                url:        "http://localhost/db_test/ShowJSON_PostedData.php",
                data:       dataRow,
                headers:    {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                onload:     function (response) {
                                if (DEBUG)  console.log (response.responseText);
                            }
            } );
        }
    }
}


//--- EOF
```

---

**Misc notes:**

1. I tested it on the main page of that site, without logging in (I'm not about to to create an account there).
2. I tested with *AdBlock*, *FlashBlock*, *NoSCript*, and *RequestPolicy* all in full effect.  JS was turned on for *bidcactus.com* (it has to be) but no others.  Turning all that crud back on shouldn't cause side effects -- but if it does, I'm not going to debug it.
3. Code like this has to be tuned for the site and for how you browse said site<sup>1</sup>.  It's up to you to do that.  Hopefully the code is self-documented enough.
4. Enjoy!

---

<sup>1</sup> Mainly: the `@include` and `@exclude` directives, the JSON data selection and filtering, and whether iFrames need to be blocked.  Also it is recommended that the 2 `DEBUG` variables (one for GM scope and one for the page scope) be set to `false` when the tuning is done.

Comment: This worked nicely for me but I had to replace the CDATA construct  because I think E4X support was removed from recent browsers. I used a simple string and scriptNode.innerHTML instead of scriptNode.textContent.

Comment: @AlvaHenrik Yes, E4X has been dead for a while now; I'll update this answer at some point.  (Oddly enough, Tampermonkey may still provide special support for CDATA used this way.)

Answer (score -4):

This isn't achievable with javascript/jquery's ajax request, because of [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

I'm not experienced with greasemonkey, through

Comment: This is fully achievable with Greasemonkey, which is not restricted by Same-origin.