# How do I make Greasemonkey do something when an AJAX call returns?

Tags: javascript, ajax, event-handling, youtube, greasemonkey

On YouTube, when I click `trending` it makes an AJAX call to fetch the trending videos.

Now, I've made a script that will remove any videos that I've already seen.

That script works fine for the frontpage, but I want the script to also be executed when I click `trending`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept the AJAX calls like:

- [This answer (generic JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/629782/331508)
  or
- [This answer (practical Greasemonkey)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6805461/331508)

But that gets messy and you have the problem of telling the AJAX calls you care about from the ones you don't.

In practice, it's simpler to just focus on the end result HTML and process it as it changes.

I have a handy utility function that works very well in these situations.  See [this answer to "Fire Greasemonkey script on ajax request"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8283815/331508).

Comment: I ended up with implementing your "in practice" example where I just check the page every second and handle the links and add a `done` class to them. I'm going to ask a new SO question asking whether I can do this when the DOM changes...

Comment: Hmm. Not clear what you're asking. If you are using `waitForKeyElements()` it does that.  It's default mode is to check as long as the page is loaded.  I'll go to the new question now.

Answer (score 0):

What about attaching a jquery listener to the click point ??

```
jQuery("a[data-feed-name='trending']").click(function(){
 alert('trending clicked')
});
```

FYI, include the jquery lib before this script :)

Comment: The problem with this is that the script fires before the AJAX call has been performed...