# Is it possible to capture XHR response data using WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing small bot using Selenium WebDriver. 
Is it possible to capture data from response of XmlHttpRequests using browsermob-proxy or any different way? I need to inspect received data from POST/GET queries. 
Actually question more related to functionality of browsermob-proxy and I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: were u able to find answer to this question?

Comment: Any updates on this question?

Comment: with a proxy, yes

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is no, but you could have Selenium execute javascript to send the post/get and retrieve the response headers... I use something like this to display errors (jqXHR is jQuery's response XML object: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

```
$.post(destURL, formresult, function (data) {

//... process return data

}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
    DisplayError(jqXHR, textStatus, error);


});
```

Answer (score -1):

I can only imagine the usual methods to intercept AJAX calls with Javascript or GreaseMonkey. I had fine results with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6805461/3034120
You can replace the output to log to create a div and fill it with the responses for example. Then you could read that out with Selenium.

Comment: Has anyone tried this with selenium and verify this worked? (asking because no upvotes)

Comment: That's not really what is asked here. Anyone maybe have a solution with Python and Selenium?