# Code works as an Opera UserJS, but gives "undefined" errors in Chrome and Greasemonkey userscripts

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, greasemonkey, userscripts, userjs

I am trying to write a cross-browser userscript that hides IMDb's rating and replaces it with a link that allows the user to rate the show/film later on.

In Opera, this approach already works, but Firefox and Chrome both stumble upon an undefined function and/or variable. here's my code so far:

```
function hideimdbratings() {

    if (document.getElementsByClassName("star-box")[0]) {

        reenabled = document.getElementsByClassName("star-box")[0].innerHTML;

        document.getElementsByClassName("star-box")[0].innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="showvote" onclick="reenableit();">Rate!</a>';

    }
}

function reenableit() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("star-box")[0].innerHTML = reenabled;
}

window.addEventListener('load', hideimdbratings, false);
```

The first part works fine, `hideimdbratings()` is executed and hides the rating.

But, upon clicking the "Rate!"-link, Firefox and Chrome both say that `reenableit()` is not defined.

Trying this:

```
onclick="document.getElementsByClassName(\"star-box\")[0].innerHTML = reenabled;"
```

Results in them saying `reenabled` is not defined.

I tried putting the code directly into the event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
// ...
}, false);
```

and this way of defining the functions (with unsafeWindow for Firefox):

```
var window.reenableit = function() { }
```

But, whatever I do, both `reenableit()` and `reenabled` remain undefined. From what I understand, neither the function nor the variable are global in browsers other than Opera, but I can't seem to find a solution just yet.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code won't work in Chrome because Chrome userscripts operate in a sandbox (["isolated world"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10828021/331508)), and you cannot set or use page-scope javascript objects in Chrome.  And, Chrome does not fully/properly support `unsafeWindow`.

The code *would* work in Firefox+Greasemonkey with careful use of `unsafeWindow`, but that is not recommended here (and won't help with Chrome).

The classic approach, when one needs to interact with page-scope javascript in a cross-browser way is to use [*Script Injection*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9526370/331508).  This is the only thing that works well in Chrome.

**However**, the smartest thing to do is not use page-scope JS at all if you don't have to.  And, for what's in this question, you don't need to. (Hint: never use `onclick` or similar attributes!  Always use `addEventListener()`, or equivalent.)

Refactoring the code to avoid leaving the sandbox scope, it becomes:

```
function hideImdbRatings () {
    var oldStarBoxHTML;
    var starBox = document.getElementsByClassName ("star-box");
    if (starBox.length) {
        starBox             = starBox[0];
        oldStarBoxHTML      = starBox.innerHTML;
        starBox.innerHTML   = '<a href="#" id="showVote">Rate!</a>';

        document.getElementById ("showVote").addEventListener (
            "click",
            function () {
                //-- "this" is a special javascript scope.
                this.innerHTML = oldStarBoxHTML;
            }
        );
    }
}

window.addEventListener ('load', hideImdbRatings, false);
```

**However 2**, you'll notice that ***all*** of the code so far, busts the interaction of IMDB's rating widget.  This is because it's overwriting `innerHTML`, which trashes the widget's event handlers.  Don't use `innerHTML` like that.

The smartest-er thing to do is to hide the block, similar to Geo's answer, like so:

```
 function hideImdbRatings () {
    var starBox = document.getElementsByClassName ("star-box");
    if (starBox.length) {
        starBox                 = starBox[0];
        starBox.style.display   = 'none';
        var rateLink            = document.createElement ('a');
        rateLink.id             = 'showVote';
        rateLink.href           = '#';
        rateLink.textContent    = 'Rate!';

        starBox.parentNode.insertBefore (rateLink, starBox);

        document.getElementById ("showVote").addEventListener (
            "click",
            function () {
                //-- "this" is a special javascript scope.
                this.style.display      = 'none';
                starBox.style.display   = 'block';
            }
        );
    }
}

window.addEventListener ('load', hideImdbRatings, false);
```

---

---

There is **an additional factor that may stop the script from working in Chrome.**  [By default, Chrome userscripts may run after the `load` event.](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#run_at)  To work around that, specify `@run-at document-end` in [the metadata block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) of your script.

Comment: @BrockAdams bravo! smartest-er :-)

Comment: @BrockAdams yes, my bad. clicked.

Comment: @mihau, not bad.  Just making sure you knew, since you are new to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how to make the variable or the function global, though here's a work around that should work just fine for you:

```
function hideimdbratings() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('star-box')[0]) {

        // hide the "star-box" container
        var b = document.getElementsByClassName('star-box')[0];
        b.style.display = 'none';

        // add the "Rate!" link
        var n = document.createElement('a');
        n.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
        n.setAttribute('onclick', 'document.getElementsByClassName("star-box")[0].style.display = "block"; this.style.display = "none";');
        n.innerHTML = 'Rate!';
        b.parentNode.insertBefore(n, b.nextSibling);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', hideimdbratings, false);
```

Comment: it does, thanks!
I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong in the other approach, does anyone know?

Comment: Right approach, +1.  But don't use `onclick`, [especially in userscripts](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.232:_Event_Handlers), and avoid using `innerHTML` AMAP.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Found it. Try this:

```
var uw = (this.unsafeWindow) ? this.unsafeWindow : window;
var b = document.getElementsByClassName('star-box')[0];
uw.reenabled = b.innerHTML;
b.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName(\'star-box\')[0].innerHTML = reenabled;">Rate!</a>';
```

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303147/injecting-js-functions-into-the-page-from-a-greasemonkey-script-on-chrome)