# Javascript: Why is this JS stopping?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

This is for a Firefox addon, its a bit puzzling as after a certain point no code is being executed.

```
if (self.xmlDoc == null) return false;


    var domain_and_full_destination=processing_domain.split("  ");

    if(domain_and_full_destination[0]=="xxx.org")
    {
        //window.stop(); // Totally stop the page from loading.

        self.root_node = '';
        self.root_node = self.xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('joe_biden_is_a_moron');
        var destinations_array= new Array();

        for (var cci = 0; cci <= self.root_node.length; cci++)
        {
            self.second_node = '';
            self.second_node = self.root_node[cci];
            destinations_array[cci]=self.second_node.getElementsByTagName('riaum')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        }


alert(domain_and_full_destination[0]+"\n");
```

The `if` goes on, but I cut it short because I want to know why the alert is never getting called?

Putting my alert in the `for` loop gets called, but anything after the for loop never executes.

No errors in the Firefox error console either.

Comment: Can you clarify which alert are you referring to? I see two of them above.

Comment: Why don't you set a breakpoint in Firebug and find out for yourself? This is not a real question.

Comment: Sorry, took out one alert. I dont know how to use Firebug...

Comment: I guess you'll solve this one by learning how to use it.

Comment: @Juhana, if anyone tells you you are helpful... they are lying to you.

Comment: one possible reason maybe that there is no firstChild `self.second_node.getElementsByTagName('riaum')[0].firstChild`. One would need to run your code to actually debug it for you. Why don't you put an alert after each statement and manually check each step ( if the for loop has few iterations) or you can always learn how to debug with Firebug.

Comment: Isn't there a } missing before the alert()?

Comment: All you have to do is look at the error console in any browser to see what javascript error is being reported.  It's absolutely silly to develop in javascript and not know how to use the most basic tools.  You should invest the time (a few minutes) to learn how to view the error console in your favorite browser and learn how to use the debugger in your favorite browser (perhaps an hour to learn the basics).  There is a ton of helpful intro doc on the web - all you have to do is Google and read.

Comment: Read my OP, there is no errors in the error console

Comment: AFAIK extension errors don't show up in the error console by default. I wasn't kidding, you'll do yourself a favor by learning the tools.

Comment: @juhana... ok, will dl FB, any tuts you recommend?

Comment: Here are some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239118/how-can-i-debug-a-firefox-extension-with-firebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's not throwing? You're doing something wrong there.

```
for (var cci = 0; cci <= self.root_node.length; cci++)
```

should be

```
for (var cci = 0; cci < self.root_node.length; cci++)
```

The fact that you used `<=` there means that, on the last iteration of the loop, `self.second_node` is actually set to undefined, which would make `self.second_node.getElementsByTagName('riaum')` throw an exception.

Comment: Ok, made the change you suggested and now it is throwing: `Error: self.second_node is undefined`

Comment: ok, using alerts I see that there were just 2 results but it was counting 0,1,2 which was causing the problem. Still dont know why exactly it did not show in the error consol in the beginning but your answer was the closest so am accepting it. Thakns everyone!

Answer (score 1):

missing a close bracket for if statement...?

Ivo Stoykov

Comment: No, i checked that first, I just posted the first few lines till it stopped working... no use posting the other stuff if its not reaching there...

Answer (score 1):

You mention that `for` loop gets called but can you alert just before for loop ends to see if it iterates / exits the loop.

Placing alerts can help you debug if you are a beginner and do not know how to use debugging tools. However in the longer run you may want to use these tools to help you get the job done much faster.

Comment: yep, it is popping the alert as long as i put it at the end of the for, but not outside

Comment: For each iteration from `0` to `self.root_node.length`? As you mention that it throws an exception.. would mean at one point it should not pop an alert.

Answer (score 0):

try to devide this line into few variables

```
destinations_array[cci]=self.second_node.getElementsByTagName('riaum')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

i.e.

```
var riaum = self.second_node.getElementsByTagName('riaum')[0] || null;
var child = riaum.firstChild || '';
var nodeVal = child.nodeValue || '?';
destinations_array[cci]=nodeVal;
```

you have to add checks what's in vars...

HTH

Ivo Stoykov