# Can't debug greasemonkey script using firebug or firefox debugger

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, firefox, greasemonkey

I found two posts on this but still doesn't seem to be working.  I don't see the user.js script in the drop down menu on either firebug or the built-in firefox debugger.  I'm still just learning coding and couldn't figure out the workaround strategies.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[How to debug Greasemonkey script on Firefox 30?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341199/how-to-debug-greasemonkey-script-on-firefox-30)

[How to debug Greasemonkey script with the Firebug extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490062/how-to-debug-greasemonkey-script-with-the-firebug-extension)

Firefox 35.0

Comment: After years of problems (and no real need by power developers), I don't think this is ever going to change.  Learn to code without needing a debugger (Code: console first, atomic, DRY, and unit test). ... ... If you really *must* have a debugger, write first in Tampermonkey with the `Debug scripts` option enabled. Then Chrome debug tools work. If it works in Tampermonkey, it will then work in Greasemonkey -- with only a few exceptions.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like I've got some reading to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056395/how-to-debug-greasemonkey-scripts-in-firebug

Comment: @tsh, Sadly, those previous answers were only effective for a time (and to limited extent -- except for the workaround parts). They seem to be obsolete now.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've found to debug greasemonkey scripts is to use the browser console to get clues and then add alerts in my code where I think the problem is... then if the alert doesn't show up I know the problem is earlier in the code.  My code usually ends up looking kinda like this pseudo code:

```
var i = get.value.from.page

alert(i)


do stuff to i

alert(i)

if (i===5){
do this stuff
alert ("i equaled 5")
}
else{
do this stuff instead
alert("i didn't equal 5, it equaled "+i)
}
```

Yeah, it's messy and time consuming... but it works.